# Am I breaking something if I set an autoincrement PK to 0?

Tags: mysql, primary-key, auto-increment

I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE `test_table` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name_UNIQUE` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Insert some records...

```
INSERT INTO `test_table` (`name`) VALUES ('a');
INSERT INTO `test_table` (`name`) VALUES ('b');
INSERT INTO `test_table` (`name`) VALUES ('c');
```

So I get records 1, 2 and 3 with values a, b and c respectively.

Now, I need to have a record with 0 as `id` and empty string as `name`. So I did this

```
INSERT INTO `test_table` (`id`, `name`) VALUES ('0', '');
UPDATE `test_table` SET `id`='0' WHERE `id`='4';
ALTER TABLE `test_table` AUTO_INCREMENT = 4 ;
```

Do I have a guarantee that everything will continue to work properly? Table references, auto increment sequence, etc...

Comment: Doesn't `0` mean "pick the next value".  I think `NULL` does.  Why do you want to use `0`?

Comment: *Do I have a guarantee that everything will continue to work properly?* Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Although not usual practice, a primary key can be 0 because 0 is a valid integer. If you set auto increment on the column it will normally start from 1, however, manually changing an id on an existing row to 0 will not cause any issues. If you have any foreign keys that referenced ID 4 before you changed it to 0, then you'll need to update those as well.

Note that if you use 0 in an INSERT for a primary key, MySQL interprets that as a request to generate a new key. In those cases, you can use the following to tell MySQL to interpret 0 INSERTs as a true 0, not a PRIMARY KEY generation request.

`SET SESSION sql_mode='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO';`